# Javascript localeCompare with accents is giving me strange results

Tags: javascript, unicode

I get the following on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari with the `en-US` locale:

```
'é'.localeCompare('e')    // result is 1
'éa'.localeCompare('eb')  // result is -1
```

This seems wrong to me.

I would expect that if `str1 > str2` then `(str1 + postfix1) > (str2 + postfix2)`, since that is how lexicographic ordering works. Yet the above example violates this.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Is there a way to do proper lexicographic ordering in Javascirpt?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the language code to compare to.

If you compare it in spanish:

```
'é'.localeCompare('e', 'es') //=> 1
'éa'.localeCompare('ea', 'es') //=> 1
'éa'.localeCompare('eb', 'es') //=> -1
```

Different languages give different results as you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Using_locales)

You can play at the snippet I've created.

Cheers!

```js
function doit() {
  var char1 = document.getElementById('char1').value;
  var char2 = document.getElementById('char2').value;
  var lang = document.getElementById('lang').value;
  document.getElementById('res').value = char1.localeCompare(char2, lang);
}
```

```html
C1: <input id="char1" value="é"><br>
C2: <input id="char2" value="e"><br>
Lang: <input id="lang" value="es"><br>
Result: <input id="res"><br>
<input type="button" value="Do it" onclick="doit()">
```